# xcode doesn't show all numbers that I type in debug area

Tags: xcode, terminal

My Xcode (version 4.5) shows me only the first number (or character) when I type in debug area - like this:

---

```
2012-09-26 02:45:31.560 nn[731:303] Which numbers do you want to calculate Great Common Divisor? 

 1st=

4

2012-09-26 02:45:36.777 nn[731:303] 2nd=

6

2012-09-26 02:45:39.633 nn[731:303] your number is 45 and 66, and gcd is 3
```

---

What is wrong with it?

Though program works fine, and I can see my number when I once change output options(All Output, Target Output).

Here is the code.

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
@autoreleasepool{
    int n1, n2;
    int numerator, denominator, remainder, gcd;
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 0;
    remainder = 0;
    gcd = 0;

    NSLog(@"Which numbers do you want to calculate Great Common Divisor? \n 1st=");
    scanf("%i", &n1);
    NSLog(@"2nd=");
    scanf("%i", &n2);

    numerator = n1;
    denominator = n2;

    while (numerator % denominator != 0){
        remainder = numerator % denominator;
        numerator = denominator;
        denominator = remainder;
    }

    gcd = denominator;
    NSLog(@"your number is %i and %i, and gcd is %i", n1, n2, gcd);
}
return 0;
}
```

---

Note: This problem occured suddenly (I used to be able to see what I typed in). I checked out all my macs, and all xcodes work like this. They all show me only the first digit of number (or character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, you have without any doubt discovered a bug of the new Xcode debug window. The code is fine and if you run the compiled program in a standard console, it works as expected .

You should report the bug into the [Apple Bug Reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/) site, if you wan't do it i will do...

Comment: Do you have the same problem? Your xcode's debug area also shows only one digit?

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally got my mind at ease. Both we can report this problem to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing was happening here on my iMac, while Xcode was running fine in debugging mode on my MacBook. I thought it was a matter of setting Xcode preferences. Nevertheless, I don't know if you are aware, but Apple has already fixed this problem. You can find more information on:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html